# Query not returning all results

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, average

I have 881 rows that the query below should return, but only returns 744:

```
SELECT MIN(DateTime),AVG(ISNULL((Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP)),0))
FROM jmusa_LOG1
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime)
ORDER BY MIN(DateTime)
```

Now if I run these two queries separately I get 588 and 293,respectively,which equals the 881 I need:

```
SELECT MIN(DateTime),AVG(ISNULL((Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP)),0))
FROM jmusa_LOG1
WHERE SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP IS NULL
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime)
ORDER BY MIN(DateTime)
```

The key difference in the above statement is the WHERE statement.

```
SELECT MIN(DateTime),AVG(ISNULL((Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP)),0))
FROM jmusa_LOG1
WHERE SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime)
ORDER BY MIN(DateTime)
```

The same key difference pertains here also, expect the please note the difference in that one has IS NULL, and the other IS **NOT** NULL

**Now does anyone now why this is happening? And what my possible mistakes are that are causing the query first mentioned to not return all 881 results?**

DB Manager: SQL Server 2008 R2, and SSMS
Date Format(if necessary): YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000

Comment: Do your two separate queries have any duplicate entries GROUP BY entries?  If so, they are being double-counted in your separate queries, but joined together into a single calculation in the single query.

Comment: Nope, I was careful to check and make sure their are not duplicates

Answer (score 3):

You have combinations of:

```
DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime)
```

where DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime) takes on both NULL and not NULL values.

In other words, the groups defined by the two separate queries overlap.

Comment: Every single row in the DateTime columns is a unique value, with no value ever being NULL. Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: No, the issue is the group by.  You are creating a separate group for each hour and day in the three queries.  When you separate it into two, some hours are included in both queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - +1, assuming you mean both NULL and NOT NULL values of SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP, right?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thats the thing, each of the separate queries provide unique results, meaning when combined they should provide 881 not 744 results

Comment: Of course the results are unique.  Every row probably has a different minimum.  Put in the hour and day, and you'll see that these are repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you really sure that the combination of HH, DD and NULL(SCR1_EXHAUST) is unique?

If two rows, even if they have different DateTimes, yet manage to have same HH and DD, and one has NULL SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP while another has not null same, the GROUP BY will merge them into a single row.

In this case, you would need to group on ISNULL(SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP) too.

```
SELECT MIN(DateTime),AVG(ISNULL((Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP)),0))
FROM jmusa_LOG1
GROUP BY ISNULL(SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP, 0)=0, DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime)
ORDER BY MIN(DateTime)
```

...or else, maybe 744 rows **is** actually what you need.

Now if you want to see all dates, yet for some of those dates you have junk values, then you need to:

- prepare a first set by extracting distinct values of YYYY, MM, DD, HH, and this will be your "calendar"
- prepare a second set where you will average non-null values of temp, grouping on YYYY, MM, DD and HH
- LEFT JOIN the calendar with the data, joining on YYYY, MM, DD and HH and obtaining those, plus TEMP, and ordering by y, m, d, h.

This will give you something like,

```
Year Mo Da HH Temp
2012 07 07 00  750
2012 07 07 01  633
2012 07 07 02  NULL    <-- from 02:00 to 02:59 we only have junk!
2012 07 07 03  660     (actually, when going from summer time to winter time...)
2012 07 07 04  680
```

Comment: I tried what you just said by grouping on ISNULL(SCR_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP) but then the hourly grouping goes away.

Comment: Which means that you DO have same DD/HH and different nullness of gastemp, does it not? So maybe you really need 744 rows after all. If, in the same hourly group, you want both null-temp and non-null-temp readings to be merged, then of course the two groups must overlap, and you'll get less than 881 rows. Even though DateTimes are unique, hours are not.

Comment: Well thats the thing.  If a column during the June 6th at 8pm hour has null and non-null values then the average for that hour should be returned in such a manner to skip the null and average the non-null so essentially I want all hours of the day to be returned with no regard for the values to be averaged.  But certain days are not being returned for example from June 8 to the 16th simply do not get returned which is worrying me

Comment: But that's what Gordon Linoff was saying -- you're ignoring one of the two rows, the NULL one. So the sum can no longer give 881. You only take into account NULL rows if they are the ONLY ones at that day and hour. Sometimes they won't be alone, and those get dropped from the 881, yielding 744.

Comment: Well the thing is yea some data might be the same, I dont see why that data should be dropped.  If my clients unit spits out this number and it happens to be the same as one that occured a month ago why should they "intersect" and be grouped as 1?

Comment: @iserni you have assumed in the edit that an entire hour will be NULL, what ive only certain values in a particular hour are null? Regardless appreciate the efforts in helping me will be trying your solutions soon

Answer (score 1):

the following query should show you the lines that overlap in your 2 sets:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime)
FROM jmusa_LOG1
WHERE SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP IS NULL
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime)

intersect

SELECT DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime)
FROM jmusa_LOG1
WHERE SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,DateTime),DATEPART(DD,DateTime)
```

Comment: Now you have clued me into something.  How do I get results regardless of intersection.  Essenntially forget the intersection just send back everything?

Comment: the point here is : why do you think you should have 881 rows ? You said : it is the sum of to sets. But if the sets overlap... then the cardinality of the union is not the sum of cardinalities

Comment: My client has this log file where every minute he has data.  He wants to take that day and hour and average it all out.  Now some of those datapoints that are being averaged are going to be NULL since those are values that are "junk", others will be non-NULL

Comment: then, imho, you should exclude those junk lines by a where clause

Comment: unfortunately my client wants to see all the dates regardless of what data

Comment: you have all the dates in your 744 rows it can't be otherwise : it is what the query asks, it is what the query gets. But the result of the avg includes null value, and that is not good.

Comment: If you want "all the dates", I have edited my answer - I think that should work.

Comment: Nope it has skipped June 8-16 completely...this is my main struggle at this point in time

Comment: What data are there between 8 and 16 June? It should come out either in the NULL or NON-NULL query, or some of both. Can't see why it should just disappear! :-(

Comment: from here I will need some data to test in vivo